# Cannot use constant in pow-function

Tags: c, pow

I have defined a constant as follows

```
 #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846;
```

And I cannot use it as an argument in the pow-function

```
 double d = pow(M_PI * 2, 0.5);
```

That is - the squareroot of M_PI * 2

I get a cryptic syntax-error in eclipse

What is wrong with this code? Have no problem using the constant outside the function

Comment: I can see that `alk`s falcon eyes already solved this, however for future reference, when you get a cryptic error message it's usually very good to not just mention it in passing but to add it to the question.

Comment: As the values for `pow` are constant why not just calculate it once and define it as a constant

Comment: pow function is not always good !

Comment: @Ed Heal - thats because this is a fragment of the cumulative normal distribution function - where I calculate certain values

Comment: @user3135077 - What you wrote will be a constant? Heard of Algerbra. i.e. simplify equations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the trailing semicolon from this line:

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846;
```

to have it look like this:

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

Macros are expanded by the pre-processor before compilation, so the code passed to the compiler using your version would look like:

```
double d = pow(3.14159265358979323846; * 2, 0.5);
```

Comment: Note that `M_PI` is defined in `math.h`, bad name for a user-defined macro.

Comment: @user3135077: I know at least one person, having ran into this issue also .... a long time ago ... ;-)

Comment: @user3135077; and you would be amazed if you know who that person was!! :)

Comment: And the reason for this question - I tried to make a equation with M_PI outside the pow-function i.e. double x = M_PI * 2; no problem!

Comment: @user3135077: I doubt this. However you probably did: `... = 2 * M_PI;`